# Apex does not like my COUNT/GROUP BY sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to do this query in a Interactive Report on apex 4.0 and I keep getting the following error:

```
The report query needs a unique key to identify each row. The supplied key cannot be used for this query. Please edit the report attributes to define a unique key column. ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

If I remove the group by then it throws an error asking for group by, Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
D.DTITLE,
COUNT(DCOPY.DID) as Stock
FROM RENT
LEFT JOIN D ON RENT.DID = D.DID
LEFT JOIN DCOPY ON RENT.DID = DCOPY.DID
WHERE RENT.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY D.DTITLE
```

Table D :

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
DID VARCHAR2(10)    No  -   1
RATEID  VARCHAR2(10)    No  -   -
DESC    VARCHAR2(40)    No  -   -
DTITLE  VARCHAR2(40)    No  -   -
```

Table Rent:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
RENTID  VARCHAR2(10)    No  -   1
DUSERID VARCHAR2(10)    No  -   -
PRIORITYID  VARCHAR2(10)    No  -   -
DID VARCHAR2(10)    Yes -   -
DISPLAYID   VARCHAR2(10)    Yes -   -
DISPLAYDATE DATE    Yes -   -
DCOPYID VARCHAR2(10)    Yes -   -
```

Comment: I find no D table, nor D table alias.

Comment: D Table
Column Name Data Type Nullable Default Primary Key
DID VARCHAR2(10) No - 1
RATEID VARCHAR2(10) No - -
DESC VARCHAR2(40) No - -
DTITLE VARCHAR2(40) No - -

Comment: But you don't select from that table! (You have rent, dvd and dvdcopy.)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, you need to either specify a unique column that can be used as a link on each row to view the corresponding row details or remove the link option. By default the report assumes that you want a link on each row to view the corresponding row details (single record view).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not syntactically correct (table aliases are incorrect).  Perhaps if the query is fixed, then the code will work:

```
SELECT D.DTITLE, COUNT(dc.DID) as Stock
FROM RENT r LEFT JOIN
     DVD d
     ON r.DID = D.DID LEFT JOIN
     DVDCOPY dc
     ON r.DVDID = dc.DID
WHERE r.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY D.DTITLE;
```

Comment: Sorry I saw the mistake but its still throwing same error